# Is it possible to prefill Facebook share caption as it seems seems like some apps prefill them?

Tags: ios, facebook, share

According to Facebook Sharing policy, prefill is not allowed? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

I recently tried InstaWeather and Flickr iOS apps, and they prefill the caption. So are they really allowed?

[image]
[image]

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: No, they should not be allowed to do this either. Pre-filling the message part of any post/share is not allowed, it always has to be content created by the user, i.e. _typed in_ by them.

Comment: Are you sure, https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ please read this point - Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Comment: Nayan, can you let me know what are the apps you have released that does this ? Facebook probably dont check it so much, but it looks to me its a violation, and they have the right to bring it down

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I forwarded it to Developer Operations so they can look at it.

Comment: Thanks WizKid. Just my personal note to FB then (if ever the policy guys read this), my suggestion is to loosen up this policy. I seriously think it should be ok to prefill with "relevant" content. I was told that some dev have got their apps approved by FB for prefilling the caption. As long it is not misleading, it should be ok. FB, please consider this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in FB Dev Community (mentioned by FB guys themselves), it is clear that it is not allowed. These apps mentioned and whoever does it are clearly in violation.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/961186750591506

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your custom object/action/story. Bellow is part of the FB sharing code from my app. You can check my posts from this app on my feed in FB https://www.facebook.com/aklobanov

```
    NSURL *appUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:FB_APP_LINK_SCHEME host:FB_APP_LINK_HOST path:FB_APP_LINK];
    NSDictionary *objectProperties = @{
                                       @"og:type": @"protrackreader:jump",
                                       @"og:title": [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"F1", nil), [[self->jump number] stringValue], [[self->jump date] longDate]],
                                       @"og:rich_attachment": @"true",
                                       @"protrackreader:serial":[[self->jump altimeter] serial],
                                       @"protrackreader:freefall:value": [[self->jump freefall] stringValue],
                                       @"protrackreader:freefall:units": @"s",
                                       @"protrackreader:altitude_exit:value": [[self->jump exit] stringValue],
                                       @"protrackreader:altitude_exit:units": @"ft",
                                       @"protrackreader:altitude_open:value": [[self->jump open] stringValue],
                                       @"protrackreader:altitude_open:units": @"ft"
                                       };
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:objectProperties];
    if (object != nil)
    {
        [object setURL:appUrl forKey:@"og:url"];
        UIImage *image = nil;
        if ([self->jump profile] != nil)
        {
            ProfileGraph *graph = nil;
            graph = [[ProfileGraph alloc] initWithDataObject:[self->jump profile]];
            if (graph != nil)
            {
                graph.speedMeasureValue = self->speedMeasureValue;
                graph.altitudeMeasureValue = self->altitudeMeasureValue;
                graph.speedMeasureText = self->speedMeasureText;
                graph.altitudeMeasureText = self->altitudeMeasureText;
                graph.themeName = kCPTSlateTheme;
                image = [graph renderGraphInImageWithRectangle:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, FB_IMAGE_WIDTH, FB_IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
                graph = nil;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"protrack_reader_app"];
        }
        if (image != nil)
        {
            FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:image userGenerated:NO];
            if (photo != nil) [object setPhoto:photo forKey:@"og:image"];
        }
        FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction actionWithType:@"protrackreader:share" object:object key:@"protrackreader:jump"];
        if (action != nil)
        {
            [action setString:@"false" forKey:@"no_feed_story"];
            [action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
            FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent new];
            if (content != nil)
            {
                content.previewPropertyName = @"protrackreader:jump";
                content.action = action;
                content.contentURL = appUrl;
                FBSDKShareAPI *api = [FBSDKShareAPI new];
                if (api != nil)
                {
                    api.shareContent = content;
                    api.delegate = self;
                    api.shouldFailOnDataError = YES;
                    error = nil;
                    if (![api validateWithError:&error])
                    {
                        [error reportError];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ([api canShare])
                        {
                            if (self->hud != nil) self->hud = nil;
                            self->hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
                            self->hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
                            [self.view addSubview:self->hud];
                            self->hud.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"H9",nil);
                            [self->hud show:YES];
                            return [api share];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```